# Angualr2 AngularCLI App cannot find HTML files in node_modules library

Tags: angular, npm-install, angular2-cli

I have a Angular2 Angular-CLI app which is consuming a custom library installed via NPM (node_modules folder).  My Angular2 app can located the custom library components at design time.  However, when serving the app via ng serve, the app errors at runtime with a 404 error for HTML, CSS files that exist in the custom library installed via NPM:

http://localhost:4200/cdf-media-slider.component.html 404 (Not Found)

cdf-video.component is a custom Angular2 library I'm trying to get to work inside my app.  How do I get my app to serve components and corresponding HTML, CSS files from a library in node_modules?

Here are my particulars around Angular-CLI:

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.18
node: 6.6.0
os: win32 x64

Here's how the custom component is loading HTML file:

```
import { ... }      from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'cdf-media-slider',
    templateUrl: './cdf-media-slider.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './cdf-media-slider.component.less' ]
})
export class CdfMediaGridComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit 
{
    //IMPLEMENTATION CODE HERE...
    ...
}
```

cdf-media-slider.component.html and cdf-media-slider.component.less reside in the same folder as this component.  This code ultimately resides in node_modules.  I'm using barrel approach for surfacing code where each folder has an index.ts file that exports it's contents.  Each parent folder has an index.ts that exports it's child's index etc.

In my client app that consumes this custom component, I'm importing the component like this:

```
import { CdfMediaGridComponent }  from 'ng2cdf/index';
```

VisualStudio Code can find this file because I have intellisense and it doesn't complain about it being missing.  At run-time however, the HTML and CSS files are not found (404) and the app is looking for them at the root of the app (http://localhost:4200/cdf-media-slider.component.html).

How do you get the appropriate path to the HTML and CSS files?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you added your module into `system-config.ts `file in `barrels` const array?

Comment: And also after you added you need to run `ng serve` again.

Comment: system-config.ts?  AngularCLI did not create system-config.ts.  How is this file connected?

Comment: i'm using angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.17.  Is system-config used with this version?

Comment: Just discovered latest version of angular-cli uses webpack therefore system-config is no longer used.

Comment: Ok, Sorry, I was outdated!

Comment: How is the custom component loading the template? Could you provide the decorator code?

Answer (score 1):

WebPack is smart enough to grab those files, so long as they're being included right. If you could provide a link to the npm package it would be easier to tell, but you may just need to add a module import.

If the library doesn't have a module, you could either create one for it, or simply add the components/directives to the main module.

In your *app.module.ts* `@NgModule` declaration, add `CdfMediaGridComponent` and any other directives/components in that library to both the `declarations` and `exports` properties. 
Alternatively, it would be better to make a completely a separate module for this custom library, and just add that module to *app.module*'s `imports` property. Example:

**cdf-media.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CdfMediaGridComponent,
    CdfSliderDirective,
    EtcDirective,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  imports: [],
  exports: [
    CdfMediaGridComponent,
    CdfSliderDirective,
    EtcDirective,
    ...
  ]
})
export class CdfMediaModule {
}
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyAppComponent
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  imports: [CdfMediaModule],
  exports: [
    MyAppComponent
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 

templateUrl: 'app/cdf-media-slider.component.html',
styleUrls: [ 'app/cdf-media-slider.component.css' ]
```

Try this. Css. no less.